# Permissions dialog with fixed characters

Tags: macos

While running our own MacOS software, a permissions dialog of some kind appeared unexpectedly with random characters. See the screenshot.

We're pretty sure we're not generating this dialog, no thread is blocked in the debugger, and nothing in our software stops working if we click "Don't Allow".  The icon in the dialog is our software's icon. We're running on High Sierra.

Clicking the ? question mark goes to an empty help window.

Any clues what this could be??

Our software is an OpenGL application, it does pretty typical things like access web servers, display things on screen, save stuff to disk.

[image: Permission dialog]

Edit: For the record, since this question was closed: much later, in Mojave we're now seeing this dialog, which might be the same one but with fixed text:

[image: Permission dialog - fixed]

Comment: Is that the logo for your app?

Comment: Yes, as I said: the icon in the dialog is our software's icon.

Comment: Ah, sorry, missed that.

Comment: That looks like a complex emoticon.